# Adjust minimum and maximum size of a table in TCL

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit, tabular

I want to create a table in Tcl/Tk gui. The minimum size of every boxes of the table will be (x=10, y=2) and if any words(inserted in any box) exceeds the box's size, then it will be adjusted towards Y-axis.
Please help me.

I have tried with this code :

```
proc table {w content args} {
    frame $w -bg black
    set r 0
    foreach row $content {
        set fields {}
        set c 0
        foreach col $row {
            lappend fields [label $w.$r/$c -text $col]
            incr c
        }
        eval grid $fields -sticky news -padx 1 -pady 1
        incr r
    }
    set w
}

#--- Test:

table .t {
    {Row Head1 Head2}
    {1   abc   123123}
    {2   bcd   12341234}
    {3   cde   12345678901234567890}
}

pack .t
```

The target table will be like this :

[image: A screen shot is here of the table]

Comment: Well depends how that table is being created. Are you using the standard tablelist package for instance?

Comment: Yes @Jerry, I have updated the details of tablelist codes in the question body. Please check it and help me.

Comment: That's not really a table widget, it's a makeshift arrangement of labels. Anyway, what if the text is too long to be contained on the 2 lines? And what if the text is between 10 and 20 chars but has no spaces?

Comment: If the text is too big, then it will be 2 lines or 3 lines or more.
If there have no spaces, then also same logic will be fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following. It doesn't cater for the case when a word in a sentence is longer than the maximum column size, but it works otherwise. It will word wrap if the text is a sentence (has a space in it), or character wrap otherwise.

Note that character wrap will still take effect if there is a word with length exceeding the maximum size of a column.

```
package require Tk

proc wrap {text len} {
  if {[string len $text] <= $len} {
    # No need for wrapping
  } else {
    if {[string first " " $text] > -1} {
      # Word wrap
      set flag "\\M"
    } else {
      # Character wrap
      set flag ""
    }
    set re "^.{1,$len}$flag"
    set result [list]
    while {1} {
      regexp $re [string trim $text] res
      regsub $re [string trim $text] "" text
      lappend result $res
      if {$text eq ""} {break}
    }
    set text [join $result \n]
  }
  return $text
}

proc table {w content args} {
  frame $w -bg black
  set r 0
  foreach row $content {
    set fields {}
    set c 0
    foreach col $row {
      set text [wrap $col 10]
      lappend fields [label $w.$r/$c -text $text]
      incr c
    }
    eval grid $fields -sticky news -padx 1 -pady 1
    incr r
  }
  set w
}

table .t {
  {Row Head1 Head2}
  {1   abc   123123}
  {2   bcd   12341234}
  {3   cde   12345678901234567890}
  {4   fgh   123456789098765432101234567890}
  {5   ijk   "Data Bits per Mask"}
}

pack .t
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much @Jerry.